# How to - If using IE8 don't load web content

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a web site that is just anything but functional with IE8. 
I currently have the web site displaying a banner that takes the visitor to upgrade IE. I'd like to do more...

What I'd like to do is, display that banner in addition to a message that says something like "Sorry your browser does not meet the requirements to view this site". 
I don't want it to load any other page content.

**Is there a way to say don't load the rest of the page in the IE if statement?**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a>
    </div>

    -- Here is where I want to say DON'T LOAD ANYTHING ELSE.
    -- Maybe automatically redirect to another blank page?

<![endif]-->
```

Comment: If the rest is in some container, let's say div, you can put a `<style>` into the comment, and there make it `display: none`. Maybe not 100% valid, but it will work.

Comment: Have you tried [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic structure for such a document:

```
<body>
<!--[if lte IE 8]
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a>
    </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8] -->
    The rest of the document goes here. 
    All browsers except IE 8 and below parse this.

    ..content...

    Rigth at the end close the conditional.
<!-- <![endif]-->
</body>
</html>
```

Note that it should be `lte IE 8` to exclude version 8.

Comment: I still see the remainder of my web page. How can I say, ignore everything else?

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question, but which browser? Nothing inside the second conditional should show in IE 8 and less if you've typed it correctly.

Comment: IE 8.0.7601. I copied and pasted your text, and changed the wording. I even tried adding closing tags for the head and adding new body /body tags. Would running it compatibility mode still think it's IE8?

Comment: I am marking this as the most correct answer. What I did was create a new page specific for IE8 error display. Then I redirected it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to do this, in the `head`:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <meta  http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=i_should_fix_this_for_ie8.html">
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
        <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode"><img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." /></a>
    </div>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 9]-->
    Here's where IE 9+ content goes (as well as content for any other browser).
<!--[endif]-->
```

**Edited** as per Juhana's suggestions below.

Comment: That would mean people using IE 9 and up get a blank page.

Comment: That's true. I kind of skipped over the fact that he wanted IE 9 and 10 to still work. Whoops!

Comment: In fact, this won't work at all because all the other browsers see it as a comment. It should start with `<!--[if !IE] -->`.

Answer (score 0):

Really you could do something javascript to hide the page, such as hiding the content, or placing a div over it, but the best thing to do would be to just let the user view the page regardless of how messed up it is. Many people are often stuck using old web browsers, and this is especially true on corporate networks. So those people may be unable to view your page at all if you do this.

Comment: This is simply not an option. There's so much JS that the page is unusable. It's not a aesthetic issue, it just doesn't load properly.